# Finding the domain of arcsin function

Tags: trigonometry

I have to find the domain of:
$ f(x) = 10 \frac{2}{3\arcsin x^2}$

Assumption 1:

$-1 \leq 3\arcsin x^2 \leq 1$

$-1 \leq x^2 \leq 1$

$x \in [-1;1]$

Assumption 2:

$3\arcsin x^2 \neq 0$

$x^2 \neq \sin 0$

$x^2 \neq 0$

$x \neq 0$

Answer: $D_{f} = [-1;0) \cup (0;1] $

However, the correct answer should be $D_{f} = (0, 1]$

Anyone sees mistake? :) Thanks~!

Comment: No, you are right, $D_f=[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$. Your "Assumption 1" is nonsense though. For $f(x)$ to be defined, you need obviously that $x^2\in[0,1]$ (for arcsine to be defined) and additionally that $\arcsin x^2\ne0$, that is $x\ne0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your answer is correct since the function is even i.e. $$f(x)=f(-x)$$ therefore the domain must also be symmetric

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your answer, but your first case is just incorrect.

$$\arcsin x \implies -1 \leq x \leq 1$$

Obviously, $x^2$ is non-negative.

$$\arcsin x^2 \implies x^2 \leq 1 \implies x \leq \vert1\vert \implies -1\leq x \leq 1$$